# Strange bug with anonymous methods in 'initialization' section

Tags: delphi, anonymous-methods

This unit fails to compile in XE2 Update 3 with error "Internal Error: SY6315". In XE there is no such problem.

```
unit Test;

interface

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  Proc: TProc;

implementation

initialization
   Proc := procedure
    var ByteArr: array of Byte;
    begin
      SetLength(ByteArr, 10);
    end;

end.
```

Does anyone have any experience of this problem?

**Update**: I have submitted a QC report: [QC#102888](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=102888).

Comment: Internal errors should not surface, you should report this to http://qc.embarcadero.com .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like a compiler bug, this is a workaround using [`TBytes`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.TBytes)

```
   Proc := procedure
    var
     ByteArr: TBytes;
    begin
      SetLength(ByteArr, 10);
    end;
```

Comment: +1,nice answer   hey how did you figure that out? plain experience?

Comment: Do you tested if using another declared type for `array of byte` works also? If so, indicates an error treating in-place types on anonymous methods.